# Scrolling bottom div only, menu and post div fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

Thank you to any who take the time to read this question.  I sincerely hope that I have provided a brain teaser, because I've searched all over for a solution, and thus far it's eluded me.  I'm a novice and have garnered a LOT of excellent ideas from this site, so my apologies if this is an easy one ...

I am trying to create a web page with a div used as a menubar towards the top, a 124px high div that will be used to write posts and submit them via ajax, and the bottom div should fill the rest of the page and will be where all posts are displayed.

The bottom div is where I'm having my troubles.  I'd love for all 3 divs to stay where they are, the page should not scroll off the bottom so the menubar is always visible, and only the bottom div should scroll when there are more messages than the size of the div.

I transferred what I have been trying to create over to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jLe1552h/14/).  Any advise would be so greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
  <div id="chatWrapper">
    <div id="room">testroom</div>
    <div id="post">Msg writing area 124px high ...</div>
    <div id="mesg">Posts ...<br>
      1<br>
      2<br>
      3<br>
      4<br>
      5<br>
      6<br>
      7<br>
      8<br>
      9<br>
      10<br>
      11<br>
      12<br>
      13<br>
      14<br>
      15<br>
      16<br>
      17<br>
      18<br>
      19<br>
      20<br>
      21<br>
      22<br>
      23<br>
      24<br>
      25<br>
      26<br>
      27<br>
      28<br>
      29<br>
      30<br>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
    background: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#before, #after {
    width: 98%;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#topbar {
    width: 98%;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#menuDiv {
    height: 24px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

#menu-button {
    height: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu { display: none; overflow: hidden; }

#chatWrapper {
    width: 98%;
    min-height: 96%;
    height: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#room { display: none; }

#post {
    width: 98%;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#mesg {
    width: 98%;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the topbar on the top, you can use `position: fixed; top: 0;`

See your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLe1552h/16/

`position: fixed;` means, that the container should stay on it's position (relative to the browser viewport) and should not be influenced by scrolling.

`top: 0;` Sets the position. It says that the  spacing between the top edge of your container and the border of your browser view should be zero.

You can also use `left`, `right` and `bottom` for the other sides and combine those values.

Alternatevly, you could also take a look at HTML5`s [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer, and example.  However, in the provided fiddle there are 30 lines (simulating posts made) and I cannot see them all because I cannot scroll down.  I looked at your example, and it appears that the post area no longer exists.

Comment: That's strange, they appear to me. Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: I now see what you mean.  You set the "mesg" div to position: fixed and told it to start 12% of the way down the window.  So that is the reason why I am not seeing the 124px high "post" div, because the "mess" give is taking up more space.  I'm trying to write a fun little chat script, and one of the crucial things is that if they are on a mobile device, I'd like for them to be able to hide the "post" div (using jquery toggle), and have the "mess" div assume the full height of the chatWrapper.  My most sincere apologies for not conveying that sooner.